# kong gateway add headers

Tags: api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

I want to add some headers to my incoming rest api requests with kong gateway.
In the kong admin UI, I set these parametes :

**config.add.headers: myheader: $(consumer_id)**

`myheader` is a name for new header and I want to set variable of `consumer_id` value in these header.
but after this configuration , kong gives me a empty value.
I also tried ${consumer_id} and etc ...
but none of these variables worked.!

So the question is: what's the **VARIABLE syntaxs** of consumer_id or custom_id and ... too call in kong gateway.

thx
BR

Comment: Are you using Key Authentication plugin ? `X-Consumer-ID` should be already set

Comment: are you using the OSS request transformer plugin (https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/request-transformer/) or some other plugin specific for Kong Enterprise like Request Transformer Advanced?

Comment: have you tried consumer.id instead of consumer_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found the correct header from network dump, and replace it with My required header.

the right header for my case was : `X-Consumer-Custom-ID`